# SVG Text bounding box is different from browser to browser when using @font-face?

Tags: text, svg, cross-browser, font-face, bounding-box

I am trying to place an SVG Text-element according to the width and height of the text by getting the bounding box using the getBBox() method.

If the text is using a websafe font, this works reasonably well across different browsers, but if the text is styled using @font-face and a custom webfont, then the width of the text is returned incorrectly in Firefox (Mac) and Safari (iOS).
It works perfectly in both Safari (Mac) and Chrome (Mac).

If the gray box has the same width as the text, then it works in that browser.

Does anybody have an idea on how to get the correct width of the text bounding box in all browsers?

Answer (score 5):

The browser is calculating the bounding box before it has finished loading/applying `@font-face`, assuming you don't need IE, you can wrap your BBox calculation function inside a `document.fonts.ready` promise...

```
document.fonts.ready.then(() => const bbox = textEl.getBBox());
```

Here is an example at work that exhibits the problem and the fix:

```js
const xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
const correct = document.getElementById("correct");
const incorrect = document.getElementById("incorrect");

visualizeBBox(incorrect);
document.fonts.ready.then(()=> visualizeBBox(correct));


function visualizeBBox(el){
  const bbox = el.getBBox();
  const rect = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "rect");
  for (prop in bbox) rect.setAttribute(prop, bbox[prop]);
  document.querySelector("svg").appendChild(rect);
}
```

```css
svg text {
  font-family: 'Diplomata SC', serif;
}

svg rect {
   stroke: red;
   fill: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Diplomata+SC&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<svg xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="400">
  <text x="0" y="40" font-size="24" id="correct">Correct dimensions</text>
  <text y="100" font-size="24" id="incorrect">Incorrect dimensions</text>
<svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I actually had exactly the same thought earlier today, so I already added that test to the example and it works!

Comment: @MadsBuchStage Updated this answer with a more robust solution

Answer (score 1):

Today I ran into similar issue. Duopixel is right that getBBox() might return momental metric which may be unexpected because external font hasn't been loaded yet and some standard font is used instead.

The problem in WebKit (tested in Chrome 24.0.1312.52 and 26.0.1389.0 canary) is that the browser defers external font loading until it is first effectively used anywhere on the page. So even if you wait for onreadystatechange to become "complete" you are not guaranteed to have font metrics ready when calling getBBox() - you may still be the first one rendering a text styled with external font, inserting it into the document and immediately calling getBBox() on it (my case).

My workaround instead of calling mySVGInitCode() directly I do:

```
$("body").append(
  $("<div/>")
    .attr("class", "force-external-font-loading")
    .attr("style", "font-family: \"xkcd\";visibility:hidden;position:absolute")
    .text("x")
  );
setTimeout(function(){ mySVGInitCode() }, 100); // 100ms is just arbitrary waiting time which should be sufficient for fetching the external font on a fast network, anyone has a better solution?
```

As you can see I dynamically insert absolutely positioned styled piece of text to force external font loading (visibility:hidden is important here instead of display:none). Then I wait some time before I execute my SVG code which could potentially render something and then immediately ask for metrics.