# SVG incorrect text BBox calculation when google fonts used

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to generate a line dynamically based on a `text`'s `BBox` created previously. However, the line is placed inaccurately.  I was hoping for the code to place the line at the beginning of the text and not far from `text`.

I am not sure what has gone wrong here. `BBox` returns the smallest possible rectangle around the `svg` element, but why the line is placed far away when it is based on the same `BBox` dimension.

```js
const body = d3.select('body');

//global specs
const width = 1536;
const height = 720;
const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';

//generate svg
const svg = body.append('svg')
    .attr('xmlns', svgns)
    .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

//background rect 
svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'vBoxRect')
    .attr('width', `${width}`)
    .attr('height', `${height}`)
    .attr('fill', '#EFEFEF');

//text data
const data = [{ "cat": "This is a test of text using Javascript" }];

//create grp
const grp = svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'test')
    
//create text  
const svgText1 = grp
    .append('g')
    .classed('svgText', true)
    .selectAll('text')
    .data(data)
    .join('text')
    .attr('class', (d, i) => { return `textSvgOne` + `${i}` })
    .each(
        function(d, i) {
            const element = svg.node();
            const vBox = element.viewBox.baseVal;
            const width = vBox.width / 2;
            const height = vBox.height / 2;

            d3.select(this)
                .attr('x', `${width}`)
                .attr('y', `${height}`)


        }
    )
    .text((d, i) => { return d.cat })
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('dominant-baseline', 'middle')
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
    .style('font-size', 'xx-large')
    .style('font-family', "'Oswald', sans-serif");


//create line 
const border1 = d3.select('g.svgText')
    .selectAll('line')
    .data(data)
    .join('line')
    .each(
        function(d, i) {
            const current = d3.select(this);
            const target = current.node().parentNode.childNodes[0];
            const box = target.getBBox();
            const x = box.x;
            const y = box.y;
            const height = box.height;

            current
                .attr('class', (d, i) => { return `textSvgBorder` + `${i}` })
                .attr('x1', x)
                .attr('x2', x)
                .attr('y1', y)
                .attr('y2', `${y+height}`)
                .attr('stroke', 'black')

        }
    )
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans&display=swap');
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200&display=swap');
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="prod.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please update your example a little so that it fits in the runnable snippet (you get 100% of the post width, but only 200 pixels of height). That said: visualise your bbox using a coloured, transparent rect to see what values you're even working with.

Comment: I suppose it's calculating the position before changing the font to Osvald. You may need a promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@enxaneta** thanks for the hint. The following adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515819/svg-text-bounding-box-is-different-from-browser-to-browser-when-using-font-face) perfectly works in chrome/firefox/brave/edge.

The `BBox` calculation is wrapped in the following
promise `document.fonts.ready.then(()=>)` and the font has following declartaion now

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/" crossorigin />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200&display=block' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

```js
const body = d3.select('body');

//global specs
const width = 1536;
const height = 720;
const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';

//text data
const data = [{
    "cat": "This is a test of text using Javascript"
}];

//generate svg
const svg = body.append('svg')
    .attr('xmlns', svgns)
    .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

//background rect 
svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'vBoxRect')
    .attr('width', `${width}`)
    .attr('height', `${height}`)
    .attr('fill', '#EFEFEF');

//create grp
const grp = svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'test')

//create text
const svgText1 = grp
    .append('g')
    .classed('svgText', true)
    .selectAll('text')
    .data(data)
    .join('text')
    .attr('class', (d, i) => {
        return `textSvgOne` + `${i}`
    })
    .each(
        function(d, i) {
            const element = svg.node();
            const vBox = element.viewBox.baseVal;
            const width = vBox.width / 2;
            const height = vBox.height / 2;

            d3.select(this)
                .attr('x', `${width}`)
                .attr('y', `${height}`)


        }
    )
    .text((d, i) => {
        return d.cat
    })
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('dominant-baseline', 'middle')
    .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
    .attr('font-size', 'xx-large')
    .style('font-family', "'Oswald', sans-serif");

//create line dynamically based on text BBox upon promise fulfillment  
document.fonts.ready.then(() => {
        d3.select('g.svgText')
            .selectAll('line')
            .data(data)
            .join('line')
            .each(
                function(d, i) {
                    const current = d3.select(this);
                    const target = d3.select(`.textSvgOne` + `${i}`).node();
                    //console.log(target);
                    const box = target.getBBox();
                    const x = box.x;
                    const y = box.y;
                    const height = box.height;
          
                    current
                        .attr('class', (d, i) => {
                            return `textSvgBorder` + `${i}`
                        })
                        .attr('x1', x)
                        .attr('x2', x)
                        .attr('y1', y)
                        .attr('y2', `${y+height}`)
                        .attr('stroke', 'black')

                }
            )
    }

)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/" crossorigin />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200&display=block' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<body>
<!--
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans&display=swap');
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald:wght@200&display=block');
    </style>
-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="prod.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```